# Calling Graphviz with ProcessBuilder under Linux

Tags: java, linux, bash, processbuilder

I want to use ProcessBuilder to run Graphviz' dot command, which will then read some input file and generate an image. I have the following code that works under windows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","start","/wait","dot","-Tpng","graph.dot","-o","graph.png");
try{
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
}catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm now trying to run my program in linux, however I can't seem to execute my command. I tried running

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c","-wait","dot","-Tpng","graph2.dot","-o","graph.png");
pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c","-wait","./dot","-Tpng","graph2.dot","-o","graph.png");
pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c","-wait","./dot","-Tpng","./graph2.dot","-o","./graph.png");
pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c","dot","-Tpng","graph2.dot","-o","graph.png");
pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c","./dot","-Tpng","graph2.dot","-o","graph.png");
pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c","./dot","-Tpng","./graph2.dot","-o","./graph.png");
```

all of which don't work.

What is the linux equivalent for my working windows command?

Comment: Why are you even using `cmd` and `start` in your windows variant? Why arent you invoking dot directly?

Comment: Ok, I just assumed you couldn't call it directly. I removed the all the arguments and it now works.

Comment: Be aware though, that if graphviz writes things to the standard out or error out, that you may need to read them to ensure the application can progress (sometimes applications can seem to work until they have filled the buffer of the std/err out)